# Will adding a Private DNS zone to a VPC cause any issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, private, google-cloud-dns, google-vpc

Provided I create a Private DNS zone on GCP attached to a VPC, will this cause any issues on existing workloads currently running on the VPC? Do I need to allocate time for downtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Virtual Private Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#:%7E:text=A%20Virtual%20Private%20Cloud%20(VPC)%20network%20is%20a%20virtual%20version%20of%20a%20physical%20network%2C%20implemented%20inside%20of%20Google%27s%20production%20network%2C%20using%20Andromeda.) (VPC) network is a virtual version of a physical network, implemented `inside of Google's production network`, using Andromeda.

[Private DNS zones](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/introducing-private-dns-zones-resolve-to-keep-internal-networks-concealed) are part of [Google Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#:%7E:text=Cloud%20DNS%20lets%20you%20publish%20your%20zones%20and%20records%20in%20DNS%20without%20the%20burden%20of%20managing%20your%20own%20DNS%20servers%20and%20software.) which lets you publish your zones and records in its DNS without the burden of managing your own DNS servers and software. Updating DNS records within a Private DNS zone should not require longer periods of propagation time unlike Public DNS zones.

Both of these features/resources are managed by Google Cloud Platform's own production network and DNS. These are different from resources that you manually provision with limited spec, so creating a Private DNS zone and associating it to an existing VPC running with workloads should not affect its performance or cause downtime.